# Elasticsearch phrase suggester is suggesting me suggestions that do not exists in my index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index where I have some data. I implemented and `did-you-mean` feature so when the user write something misspelled it could receive a suggestion with the right words.

I used the phrase suggester because I need suggestions for short phrases, like names for example, the problem is that some suggestions do not exists in the index.

Example:

```
document in the index: coding like a master
search: Codning like a boss
suggestion: <em>coding</em> like a boss
search result: not found
```

My problem is that, there are no phrase in my index that match the specified suggestion, so it's recommending me phrases that do not exists and thus will give me a not found search.

What can I do with this? Shouldn't phrase suggester give suggestions for phrases that actually exists in the index?

Here I'll leave the corresponding query, mapping and setting just in case you need it.

**Setting and Mappings**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 3,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn": "2s",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.default.filter.0": "standard",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.default.tokenizer": "standard",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.default.filter.1": "lowercase",
      "index.analysis.analyzer.default.filter.2": "asciifolding",
      "index.priority": 3,
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "suggests_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "lowercase",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "shingle_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "shingle_filter": {
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3,
            "type": "shingle"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "suggest_field": {
          "analyzer": "suggests_analyzer",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
  "DidYouMean": {
    "text": "Codning like a boss",
    "phrase": {
      "field": "suggest_field",
      "size": 1,
      "gram_size": 1,
      "confidence": 2.0
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is expected actually. If you analyze your document with [analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html), you will get a better picture of what is happening.

```
GET suggest_index/_analyze?text=coding like a master&analyzer=suggests_analyzer
```

This is the output

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "coding",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "coding like",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 11,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "coding like a",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 13,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "like",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 11,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "like a",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 13,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "like a master",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 20,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "a",
         "start_offset": 12,
         "end_offset": 13,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "a master",
         "start_offset": 12,
         "end_offset": 20,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "master",
         "start_offset": 14,
         "end_offset": 20,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, there is a token "coding" generated for the text and hence it is in your index. It is **not** suggesting you something that is not in index.If you strictly want phrase search, then you might want to consider using [keyword tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html). For e.g if you change your mapping to something like

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "suggests_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "lowercase",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "shingle_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom"
          },
          "raw_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "shingle_filter": {
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3,
            "type": "shingle"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "suggest_field": {
          "analyzer": "suggests_analyzer",
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "analyzer": "raw_analyzer",
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then this query will give you expected results

```
{
  "DidYouMean": {
    "text": "codning lke a master",
    "phrase": {
      "field": "suggest_field.raw",
      "size": 1,
      "gram_size": 1
    }
  }
}
```

it wont show anything for *"codning like a boss"*.

**EDIT 1**

2) From your comments and also from running some phrase suggestions on my own dataset, I feel a much better approach would be to use [`collate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-suggesters-phrase.html#_basic_phrase_suggest_api_parameters) option `phrase suggester` provides so that we can check every suggestion against a `query` and give back suggestion only if it is going to get back any document from index. I have also added `stemmers` to mapping to consider only root word. I am using `light_english` as it is less aggressive. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/algorithmic-stemmers.html) on that.

Analyzer part of mapping looks like this now

```
 "analysis": {
     "analyzer": {
         "suggests_analyzer": {
             "tokenizer": "standard",
             "filter": [
                 "lowercase",
                 "english_possessive_stemmer",
                 "light_english_stemmer",
                 "asciifolding",
                 "shingle_filter"
             ],
             "type": "custom"
         }
     },
     "filter": {
         "light_english_stemmer": {
             "type": "stemmer",
             "language": "light_english"
         },
         "english_possessive_stemmer": {
             "type": "stemmer",
             "language": "possessive_english"
         },
         "shingle_filter": {
             "min_shingle_size": 2,
             "max_shingle_size": 4,
             "type": "shingle"
         }
     }
 }
```

Now this query will give you desired results.

```
{
   "suggest" : {
     "text" : "appel on the tabel",
     "simple_phrase" : {
       "phrase" : {
         "field" :  "suggest_field",
         "size" :   5,
         "collate": {
           "query": { 
             "inline" : {
               "match_phrase": {
                   "{{field_name}}" : "{{suggestion}}" 
               }
             }
           },
           "params": {"field_name" : "suggest_field"}, 
           "prune": false
         }
       }
     }
   },
   "size": 0
 }
```

This will give you back *apple on the table*
Here `match_phrase` query is used which will run every suggested phrase against index. You can make `"prune" : true` and see all results that have been suggested regardless of the match. You might want to consider using `stop` filter to avoid stopwords.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I'll give this a try right now. About the `shingle filter`, I think you're right. I really wasn't using the `shingle_filter` until now, when I was looking for a solution to this problem and some post recommend it for a `did-you-mean` feature.

Comment: Hey, I just try this, and it was right what I need, thanks! By the way, did you know a way to deal with plurals there? I mean, to get a suggestions neither I write _apple_ or _apples_ for example. I know about the `snowball` filter, but since it works by token, and the `keyword` tokenizer produces one single token it's not really accurate in this case: _apples on the tables_, which produces: _apples on the table_, any idea?

Comment: Hey, I have updated my answer. Please have a look. It should take care of everything you suggested. Let me know if something does not work

Comment: I'm pretty sure when I say your answer tackle down the problem I was facing, I'm really thankful, and appreciate you effort, i mean it. I owe you one :)
By the way, I'm wondering, which performance consequences could the `collate` have? I'll do my research of course, but if you know something, I'll be more than glad to here it

Comment: glad I could help, there was [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9377) when firing multiple phrase suggest request but It has been resolved, apart from that I dont think It has any issues.