# Elasticsearch phrase suggester not working as expected, only gives one good fix

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the folliwng `book` indexed:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/books/book/1 -d '{
    "title": "All Quiet on the Western Front",
    "author": "Erich Maria Remarque",
    "year": 1929,
}'
```

I'm trying to implement a *Phrase Suggester* using the code of the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-suggesters-phrase.html).

So I tried;

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/books/_search' -d '{
  "suggest" : {
    "text" : "al quet",
    "simple_phrase" : {
      "phrase" : {
        "analyzer" : "body",
        "field" : "bigram",
        "size" : 1,
        "real_word_error_likelihood" : 0.95,
        "max_errors" : 0.5,
        "gram_size" : 2,
        "direct_generator" : [ {
          "field" : "title",
          "suggest_mode" : "always",
          "min_word_length" : 1
        } ],
        "highlight": {
          "pre_tag": "<em>",
          "post_tag": "</em>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I'm expecting this to correct from `al quet` to `all quiet`.

But I get the following error:

```
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Analyzer [body] doesn't exists"
```

If I change `"analyzer" : "body"` to `"analyzer" : "title"` I get the same error but with `title`:

```
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Analyzer [title] doesn't exists"
```

If I change `"analyzer" : "body"` to `"analyzer" : "default"` it doesn't show an error in that line, but it shows an error in the next line. `"field" : "bigram",`

```
  "error" : {
     "root_cause" : [ {
       "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
       "reason" : "No mapping found for field [bigram]"
```

The only way to make this work is to add: `"analyzer" : "default",` and `"field" : "title",`:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/books/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "suggest" : {
    "text" : "al quet",
    "simple_phrase" : {
      "phrase" : {
        "analyzer" : "default",
        "field" : "title",
        "size" : 1,
        "real_word_error_likelihood" : 0.95,
        "max_errors" : 0.5,
        "gram_size" : 2,
        "direct_generator" : [ {
          "field" : "title",
          "suggest_mode" : "always",
          "min_word_length" : 1
        } ],
        "highlight": {
          "pre_tag": "<em>",
          "post_tag": "</em>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

With this I'm getting this output:

```
 "suggest" : {
    "simple_phrase" : [ {
      "text" : "al quet",
      "offset" : 0,
      "length" : 7,
      "options" : [ {
        "text" : "al quiet",
        "highlighted" : "al <em>quiet</em>",
        "score" : 0.09049256
      } ]
    } ]
  }
```

As you can see it's correcting `quiet` but not `al`, With all my other tries is happening the same, it only corrects one word.

How can I make a succesfull phrase suggester that in the example you input `al quet` and returns `all quiet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the first error because there is no `analyzer` named *body* in your index and same with *title*

The second error is due to missing field *bigram*, you have only three fields in your index namely *title*, *author*, and *year*.

With your current setup, for `suggester` to work correctly, you need to give high value for `max_errors`. From the docs, max_errors is

> the maximum percentage of the terms that at most considered to be
>   misspellings in order to form a correction. This method accepts a
>   float value in the range [0..1) as a fraction of the actual query
>   terms or a number >=1 as an absolute number of query terms. The
>   default is set to 1.0 which corresponds to that only corrections with
>   at most 1 misspelled term are returned. Note that setting this too
>   high can negatively impact performance. Low values like 1 or 2 are
>   recommended otherwise the time spend in suggest calls might exceed the
>   time spend in query execution.

so this should give you desired output.

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "al quet",
    "simple_phrase": {
      "phrase": {
        "analyzer": "default",
        "field": "title",
        "size": 1,
        "real_word_error_likelihood": 0.95,
        "max_errors": 0.9,  <--- increase this value
        "gram_size": 2,
        "direct_generator": [
          {
            "field": "title",
            "suggest_mode": "always",
            "min_word_length": 1
          }
        ],
        "highlight": {
          "pre_tag": "<em>",
          "post_tag": "</em>"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

You might want to use `shingles` for phrases and `collate` to get only those results which are in index. I have given detailed answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819812/elasticsearch-phrase-suggester-is-suggesting-me-suggestions-that-do-not-exists-i/34821816#34821816) which might help.